# Count of distinct values with where filter in Spring Data Query Methods

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity like this below

```
@Entity
public class Example
{
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name = "pl_id")
 private Long id;

 @Column(name = "pl_date")
 @Convert(converter = DateConverterFromString.class)
 private LocalDateTime date;

 @Column(name = "pl_number")
 private String number;

 @Column(name = "pl_type")
 private Long result;

 @Column(name = "pl_package_id")
 private Long packageId;
 // getters&setters
}
```

I'm trying to get the number of unique pl_number results for a given type.
Like, I'm trying to make hibernate run this query for me

```
select count(distinct pl_number) from sample_table where pl_type=200;
```

What I have tried so far are Spring Data Query Methods and JPQL or native queries.

I did

```
countDistinctNumberByResult(Long result);
```

and I also tried to write a native and jpql query for this. But what it returns is a query like below

```
select
    distinct count(distinct provisionl0_.pl_id) as col_0_0_ 
from
    sample_table provisionl0_ 
where
    provisionl0_.pl_type=? 
    and (
        provisionl0_.pl_date between ? and ?
    )
```

Anyone has a fix or a better idea?
Thanks.

Comment: What is the native query that you specified? And the query you posted is that the derived query from the method or from your native query?

This is not a use-case for query derivation, but a native query should work fine and be reasonable database independent.

Comment: I fixed this with a query. But I think I should also be able to handle this with a query method. However, I could never get it to working.